# Creating blank/deleting rows form excel using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel, integration

I have an .xlsx file I import data from nightly.
Once the import is complete I delete the tables(sheets/tabs) in the excel file using an Execute SQL Task so that the file is blank for the user but contains correct header rows:

```
DROP TABLE `sheet1$`
GO

DROP TABLE `sheet2$`
GO
```

I then re-create the tables (sheets/tabs) using another Execute SQL Task on completion of the last:

```
CREATE TABLE `sheet1$` (
`Column 1` LongText,
`Column 2` LongText
)
GO

CREATE TABLE `sheet2$` (
`Column 1` LongText,
`Column 2` LongText,
`Column 3` LongText,
`Column 4` LongText,
`Column 5` LongText,
`Column 6` LongText
)
GO
```

The problem I have is that say 10 rows existed on day 1. 10 records are imported. The tables(sheets/tabs) are deleted. The tables(sheets/tabs) are re-created but for some reason the number of rows are still part of the sheet. So for instance if on day 2 no new records where added to the file then the import imports 10 blank rows. It's like they are being cleared but excel is holding some sort of reference to data rows.
If the file has not been added to for a few days then it just continues to import 10 blank rows each night filling up the table with nonsense rows.

Obviously I can't use the following otherwise I wouldn't have to drop and re-create.

```
DELETE * FROM `sheet1$`
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

There are many workarounds I can think off such as:

An sql script that deletes NULL rows from the SQL table where they are imported to but this messes up the auto increment ID field which I need to be the same as the record count.

So I could:

Import to an interim temp table and only import rows that contain data to the final table.

OR

After import copy data to another table, delete NULL rows, truncate original table and import back (retains ID increment)
...etc etc

I am sure the workarounds are not needed and complicating the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Using a CSV instead of Excel file will make this a lot easier and cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is the ext, name and format because another program extracts to it.

Comment: Then [transform it in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122319/ssis-process-for-saving-xlsx-file-as-csv-file) first

Comment: Instead of using Execute SQL Task to run the DROP TABLE statements, have you tried using a File System Task to remove the excel file, then running the Execute SQL Task that runs the CREATE TABLE statements? This should remove then recreate the Excel file with your column headers but no ghost rows.